# file.writelines(foo) of a sequence of non-strings, error in python

Tags: python, stdout, counter

Alright I know my error and what it means. But, could someone show me how to write a set of non-string arguments to a file?

Code that produces the error:

```
with open('count.txt', 'w') as count:
for k,v in makeddict.items():
    print "MID -",k + ':', Counter(v)
    readout = "MID -",k + ':', Counter(v)
    count.writelines(readout)
```

I totally understand that `Counter` is the cause of my error when I try this standard form of writing lines to a file. So I attempted to write my stdout to the file instead(see below).

Attempt to fix my code:

```
for k,v in makeddict.items():
    print "MID -",k + ':', Counter(v)
    sys.stdout = open('count.txt', 'w')
```

This worked, I got a single line (the first line of stdout) to write to my file. But, I would like to see all 19 other lines in my `count.txt` file.

So can anyone show me how to make my code print all my stdout into a file? Should I throw an `.append` in there? (will try this now for kicks).

OR  Could someone show me a better way to print my "print block" to a file when it has non-string arguments like `Counter` .

Comment: You could writeline `str(readout)`, which is what `print` is doing.  But you might want to think about how you're doing this and try to write it in a more structured format (like CSV or JSON) if you want to reliably read back the data later.

Comment: I am new to the realm of scripting, thank you for the pointers. I honestly need to read up on JSON and a lot of the other common jargon I see on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.stdout = open('count.txt', 'w')` truncates the file, so each changes done before are cleared when you call it.

You should be doing:

```
sys.stdout = open('count.txt', 'w')
for k,v in makeddict.items():
    print "MID -",k + ':', Counter(v)
```

Or,

```
with open('count.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k,v in makeddict.items():
        print >> f, "MID -",k + ':', Counter(v)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I figured that was what was happening. Also thank you for the new syntax " >> " I haven't seen that in Python yet. I assume it just means print the next argument to f?

Comment: @jon_shep Yes, it is a redirection of the print!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas Orozco's answer, your `readout` variable holds a tuple, not a string, so I suspect the result is not what you want. You might want to try something like:

```
readout = "MID -" + k + ':' + Counter(v)
```

This will try to make a string out of all the parts. It will fail for objects that do not have a `__str__` or `__repr__` method, though.

Comment: Good point, I ideally want all of Counter's contents in a tab delimited formate for down stream editing with Sed and Awk. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You'd probably have to iterate over the counters items and append them to the string you're building.

Comment: Sweet, I think I know how to do that one actually. :)  This would mean the iteration is a true string right? I could then use my previous methods of writing lines to a file?

Comment: The result of the iteration should be an appended string, yes. Python doesn't have a string comprehension. :-) And you could then write that to a file.